# python - how to get the data/ calculated matrix before saving to be an image?

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
from numpy import NaN
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def julia(C):
    X = arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005)
    Y = arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005)
    M = zeros((len(Y), len(X)))
    plt.axis('off')

    for x_iter, x in enumerate(X):
        for y_iter, y in enumerate(Y):
            z = x + 1j * y
            pixel = NaN
            for n in range(1, 4096):
                z = z**2 + C
                if abs(z) > 2:
                    pixel = n
                    break

            M[y_iter, x_iter] = pixel

    # (Please help! right here I want to print the intensity matrix elements out to check the actual data  values, but how to write out this piece of code?!)

    plt.imshow(M, cmap = cm.cubehelix, extent = (X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()))
    plt.savefig('julia.tiff')
```

I want to print the intensity matrix elements out to check the actual data values, but how to write out this piece of code?! Due to if I just print M by print("Calculated Matrix: ", M), I could get only all [[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] ... [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]. However, the calculated matrix elements should be any number in the range [0, 65536], not just all equal to 1! Any comment will be awesome!!

Comment: `return M` above `plt.imshow` ?

Comment: thanks m-zayan, I try your suggestion, but that does anything. Do you have any further idea?

Answer (score 0):

you get only  `1` because here：

```
for n in range(1, 4096)
   ...
    break
```

`n` is `1` and then break

Comment: maybe you can paste your code in your question area rather than comment.

Comment: Anyone on the earth who knows how to code this intensity matrix for able to print out it ?! Please show me!! Any suggestions will be thankful!